# Is there anyway to trigger on a process exit/close event in a UWP background application?

Tags: windows, events, uwp, hook, exit

I want to have logic that triggers right before my UWP process is exited or gracefully killed.  Is there anything that may accomplish what I wish to do? Or is this impossible in the UWP environment?

I know there exists a trigger for "onSuspending", but I do not want to trigger on that, I want to trigger when the process is exited or gracefully killed. I am aware of the "confirmAppClose" capability and "CloseRequested", but based on research, that seems to only be applicable for the "X" close button. I have a background task with no UI so there is not "X" button visible to trigger it. I am aware of "CoreApplication.Exiting" event but it seems like that won't work either based on what I've read.

Comment: Does my answer make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that currently, there is no other ways for UWP to handle the app close request than the `CloseRequested` event. So it is impossible to get notified when the app is forcibly closed. As you've already known, the `CloseRequested` event only works when user click the "X" Button.